# How to link NPM pacakge locally to remove dependence on remote?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package, node-modules

I am building a react project for which I am using a 3rd party library. The library is available as an npm package, which solves the purpose. But the package is unreliable as it has very few downloads and not updated in years. I am trying to use it as a local package instead of a remote one. I npm installed it, but cant figure out to link it locally. 
**Note**: I searched for other well maintained packages, but couldn't find one & I had to stick to this one.

Comment: What package are you using. You can install it globally via `npm i -g <package_name>` command, and it will not be pushed to github, Or you can create a new branch and test on that one

Comment: Use it as a local package meaning, i want to get rid of its dependence completely from the remote branch and when someone else tries to use my branch, he/she should be able to use the package without hassle. So, when i run npm install, it shouldn't refer the npm registry, but the local package.